# Javascript Error - Can't see mistake

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript. The errors are reported in lines  14 and 22; saying that there is "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" in line 14 and that "Uncaught ReferenceError: init is not defined" in line 22.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>OpenLayers Demo</title>
   <script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
   <script>
    function init(){
        map = new OpenLayers.Map("basicMap");
        var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
        map.addLayer(mapnik);//add the OSM layer to map
            var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
            map.addLayer(markers);
            var LonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(13.0,47.8);
        transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
            map.getProjectionObject();
        );
        markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(LonLat));
        map.setCenter(LonLat, 15);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload = "init()">
    <div style = "width: 100%; height: 60%;" id = "basicMap"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: The arguments to `transform` should be separated by a comma, not terminated by semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

There are some semicolons where there shouldn't be.

```
   transform(
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); // here
        map.getProjectionObject(); // here
    );
```

This should be using commas, since they are function arguments.

```
   transform(
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
        map.getProjectionObject()
    );
```

If this happens in the future, you can use code linting tools like jslint: http://www.jslint.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
            map.getProjectionObject()
        );
```

Should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The second error message is caused by the first: Because the `<script>` block where `init` was supposed to be defined contains a syntax error, it can't be loaded and therefore `init` is never defined. So when you call `init()` further down, you get a `ReferenceError`.

And the reason for the first error is here:

```
transform(
    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
    map.getProjectionObject();
);
```

Parameters are to be separated by **commas**, not **semicolons**! So JavaScript assumes that the semicolon there is the end of the statement, like this:

```
transform(   new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
```

...and because this would mean that the parens from `transform` are opened but not closed, you get this error.

So, the correct code would be:

```
transform(
    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    map.getProjectionObject()
);
```

Note that for the second parameter, I completely removed the semicolon (not replaced it by a comma) because trailing commas are not allowed.

Just for the sake of understanding: Basically, all you do here is a multiline version of this:

```
transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());
```

...so it has to follow the normal rules of function calls and their parameters.